# What are weak squares in chess; how can they help to mate another player?

Tags: theory, books

I read this concept in a book but I didn't understand much about the concept. Can anybody explain this concept with an example?

Comment: Depends on what the game looks like. Can you add an example or more information?

Comment: https://lichess.org/practice Here's some examples of common weak squares/ combos exploited

Answer (score 6):

This is a very common example.

```
[FEN "6k1/5p1p/5BpQ/8/8/8/8/6K1 w - - 0 1"]
```

Do you see the weak dark squares around the king? Checkmate is possible because those squares are weak and can't be defended.

Comment: This is a bit of a circular definition. The weak squares are the weak squares. They help mate a player because they are weak. You don't even specify which king you are talking about.

Comment: @OrangeDog It's completely obvious which king is being talked about.

Answer (score 4):

*A weak square is a square of great great importance that is difficult to cover or get rid of.*

---

Since the square is difficult to cover, it can become a great outpost for opponent's (your) pieces, usually a knight.

If you manage yo get the right piece on that square, it helps you in any kind of possible attacks. Whether the attack will result in checkmate or 'only' material advantage depends on the position.

---

It usually doesn't matter, whether there's a pawn on that square or not (as A. Nimzowitsch stated). You will have the same problems/advantages connected with it.

The only difference is that the pawn can be targeted for the sake of capturing it.

---

Recap:

There are 2 basic ways to take advantage of a weak square

1. Occupy it to get good outposts for your pieces and to get control over certain parts of the board.
2. Attack and capture the weak pawn

Note: Usually 1 weakness isn't enough to win the game, the opponent will be able to protect it. The principle of 2 weaknesses says that you have to find at least another one.